# r functions will not recognise apostrophe in character string

Tags: r, regex, character-encoding

I have a large data frame of survey data read from a .csv that looks like this when simplified.

```
x <- data.frame("q1" = c("yes","no","don’t_know"),
            "q2" = c("no","no","don’t_know"),
            "q3" = c("yes","don’t_know","don’t_know"))
```

I want to create a column using rowSums as below

```
x$dntknw<-rowSums(x=="don’t_know")
```

I can do it for all the `yes` and `no` answers easily, but In my dataframe it just generates zeros for the `don’t_know`'s. 
I previously had an issue with the apostrophe looking like this `donâ€™t_know`. I added `encoding = "UTF-8"`to my `read.table` to fix this. However now I cant seem to get any R functions to recognise it, I tried `gsub("’","",df)` but this didnt work as with `rowSums`. 
Is this a problem with the encoding? is there a regex solution to removing them? what solutions are there for dealing with this?

Comment: It works for me (using german locale)

Answer (score 1):

It is an encoding issue and not a regex one. I am unable to reproduce the issue and my encoding is set as `UTF-8` in R. Try by setting the encoding to `UTF-8` in default R rather than at the time of read.

here is my sample output with your code.

```
> x
         q1          q2         q3 dntknw
1        yes         no        yes      0
2         no         no don’t_know      1
3 don’t_know don’t_know don’t_know      3

> Sys.setlocale()
[1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"
```

Here is some more detail that may be helpful. 
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding

Answer (score 1):

As @Drj stated, it is probably an encoding error. When I paste your code into my console, I get

```
> x$q1
[1] yes             no              don<U+0092>t_know
```

Even if the encoding is off, you can still match it using regex:

```
grepl("don.+t_know", x$q1)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Hence, you can calculate the row sums as follows:

```
x$dntknw <- rowSums(apply(x, 2, function(y) grepl("don.+t_know", y)))
```

Which results in

```
> x
                 q1                q2                q3 dntknw
1               yes                no               yes      0
2                no                no don<U+0092>t_know      1
3 don<U+0092>t_know don<U+0092>t_know don<U+0092>t_know      3
```